# determine for which values of $x$ the function $f(x)=\begin{cases} \frac{x^2-4}{x-2}+10, &\text{if }x < 2\\ 2x^3-x, &\text{if } x ≥ 2\\ \end{cases}$

Tags: calculus, limits

is continuous...

$$f(x)=\begin{cases}
\frac{x^2-4}{x-2}+10, &\text{if }x < 2\\
2x^3-x, &\text{if } x ≥ 2\\
\end{cases}$$

These kind of problems are very unclear to me, I only know these kind of functions have several graphs, in this example There are 2, But I can't figure out what these intervals means and even worse I don't even know where to start from.

Comment: What does it mean for a function $f(x)$ to be continuous at $x=c$? [Here is a link for reference](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Continuous_function#Definition_in_terms_of_limits_of_functions).

Comment: Hint: $f(x) = x+12$ for $x \lt 2\,$, so $f$ is polynomial on $\mathbb{R} \setminus \{2\}\,$, thus continuous. This leaves $x=2$ to examine and determine whether $f$ is continuous or not there.

Comment: @ZubinMukerjee f(c) is defined, lim f(x) x-> exists.

Comment: @hjx Close! $f(c)$ must be defined, $\lim_{x\to c} f(x)$ must exist, **and** be equal to $f(c)$.

Comment: @hjx Now, you can split the problem into three parts - first, check whether $f(x)$ is continuous at $x=c$ when $c<2$. Then check when $c>2$. Finally, check the case of $c=2$.

Comment: @hjx If you are confused about how the function is defined, it is what is called a piecewise-defined function. [Here is a link for reference](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Piecewise#Notation_and_interpretation).

Comment: @ZubinMukerjee thanks, I'll try.

Comment: It's continuous everywhere, calculate the left hand limit as $x\rightarrow^2$ from the left, it is equal to the value at $x=2$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This would be a piecewise function! It is broken into pieces. Now let's start.

$$f(x)=\begin{cases} \frac{x^2-4}{x-2}+10, &\text{if }x < 2\\ 2x^3-x, &\text{if } x ≥ 2\\ \end{cases}$$

For a function to be continuous on a point we must have

$$\lim_{x \rightarrow a}f(x)=f(a)$$

Limit of a function exists only when

$$\lim_{x \rightarrow a^+}f(x)=\lim_{x \rightarrow a^-}f(x)$$

If $\lim_{x \rightarrow a^+}f(x)\neq \lim_{x \rightarrow a^-}f(x)$
then we say the limit does not exist!

Deal with left hand limit(values of x that is smaller than a) first

$$\lim_{x \rightarrow 2^-}\frac{x^2-4}{x-2}+10$$

Notice that direction substitution will result in indeterminate form $\frac{0}{0}$

The function can be redefined in a way such that

$$\lim_{x \rightarrow 2^-}\frac{x^2-4}{x-2}+10=\lim_{x \rightarrow 2^-}\frac{(x-2)(x+2)}{x-2}+10$$

$$\lim_{x \rightarrow 2^-}\frac{(x-2)(x+2)}{x-2}+10=\lim_{x \rightarrow 2^-}(x+2)+10$$

$$\lim_{x \rightarrow 2^-}(x+2)+10=14$$

Right hand limit

$$ \lim_{x \rightarrow 2^+}2x^3-x=2(2)^3-2$$

$$2(2)^3-2=14$$

Both sides limit are equal so we claim the limit exists and is equal to $14$

Now how about point $x=2$ we choose the following function because it contains the point that we want

$$f(x)=2x^3-x$$

$$f(2)=2(2)^3-2$$

$$f(2)=14$$

So we say that the function is continuous at $x=2$ by

$$\lim_{x \rightarrow 2}f(x)=f(2)$$

Some visual confirmation!

[image]

Notice that as x gets closer and closer to $2$ from the right side for the function $\frac{x^2-4}{x-2}+10$. Example, $1,1.5,1.66,1.99$

The function is approaching the value of $14$

In limit we don't care about what happen in at point $x=a$ We only care about what happen around it. In this case the right hand limit and the left hand limit are equal. Ergo, the limit exists.

If we were to graph the function

$$\frac{x^2-4}{x-2}+10$$

alone  for domain $(- \infty,2)(2,\infty)$
A gap will happen at point $x=2$ The gap is removable hence called removable discontinuity!

Comment: Your answer is amazing thank you very much, Only clear up something, the first function, 2 wouldn't be defined only if I couldn't factor to avoid the 0/0 ?

Comment: Even if you can factor everything out of the first function function is still undefined at that point$x=2$. it is because the original function is undefined there.
Suppose that we have two different functions $f(x)$ & $g(x)$
If you were to draw a graph of $$f(x)=\frac{x^2-4}{x-2}=x+2$$ the graph will look exactly like the graph of $g(x)=x+2$ for all values of x except there is a gap at $x=2$ for $f(x)$. But we know that as the values of x gets closer and closer to 2 without letting x be at 2. That is the concept of limit. The gap looks like a hollow circle.

Comment: In limit we only care about what happen around that point. We don't care about what happen at that point. Even though we know that the function doesn't exist at that point. But as we get closer and closer what it is the value of the function approaching.

Comment: One more question, when x ->2-, does it mean we are approaching x from the negative side to the positive side ? Since the first function has x < 2, I won't be able to approach from the positive side to the negative.

Comment: When we approach $x \rightarrow 2^{-}$ It is from the side which any number that is less that 2. Like, 0,1,1.5,1.999. Whereas $x \rightarrow 2^{+}$ means that we approach from the sides that is larger than the value of 2. Like 3,2.5,2.2,2.1. In our question the left side smaller than 2 is defined by the first function. The right side bigger than 2 is defined by the second function. That is why we approach the left side(left hand limit) by the first function and the right side(right hand limit) by the second function.

Comment: Take this as an example. 
$y=x^2$ for $x<0$.
we can have any value that is less than 1. $x=-1,y=1$, $x=-2,y=4$
$y=x$ for $x \geq 0$.
We can have $x=0,y=0$ $x=1,y=1$ 
Why did the above things happen? We provide restriction to the domain. It is something like if you want $y=x^2$ to be one to one then we restrict the domain such that $x \geq 0$. Then, we plot the graph we use the indicated domain. Piece-wise function is made up of different functions.

Comment: Thank you very much for taking the time to help me.

Comment: No problem. One year back I was in your position. I have been there too.

Answer (score 2):

As Zubin Mukerjee indicated in the comments, we must show that

1. $f$ is continuous when $x < 2$;
2. $f$ is continuous when $x > 2$;
3. $\lim_{x \to 2+} f(x) = \lim_{x \to 2-} f(x) = f(2)$.

If $x < 2$, then
\begin{align*} 
f(x) & = \frac{x^2 - 4}{x - 2} + 10\\
     & = \frac{(x + 2)(x - 2)}{x - 2} + 10\\
     & = x + 2 + 10 && \text{provided $x \neq 2$}\\
     & = x + 12
\end{align*}
Since $x < 2$, we are not dividing by zero in the second step.  Hence, the given expression is equivalent to $x + 12$ in the interval $(-\infty, 2)$.  Since $x + 12$ is a polynomial, $f$ is continuous in the interval $(-\infty, 2)$.

If $x > 2$, then $f(x) = 2x^3 - x$.  Since this is a polynomial, $f$ is continuous the interval $(2, \infty)$.

Since 
$$\lim_{x \to 2+} f(x) = \lim_{x \to 2+} (2x^3 - x) = 2 \cdot 2^3 - 2 = 16 - 2 = 14$$ 
and 
$$\lim_{x \to 2-} f(x) = \lim_{x \to 2-} (x + 12) = 2 + 12 = 14$$
and 
$$f(2) = 2 \cdot 2^3 - 2 = 16 - 12 = 14$$
it is true that 
$$\lim_{x \to 2+} f(x) = \lim_{x \to 2-} f(x) = f(2)$$

Since we have verified all three conditions, $f$ is continuous on $(-\infty, \infty)$.